# Arithmetic Mean/Geometric Mean Inequality

Tags: real-analysis

We have to use the arithmetic mean/geometric mean inequality.
Let $a$ and $b$ be fixed positive numbers. Find the value of $x>0$ that minimizes the given expression and determine the minimum value of the expression,
$ax+\frac{b}{x}$.

I don’t know how to get started by transforming the expression to be able to use the mean inequality. We were told not to solve using calculus.

Comment: If you were told "not to solve using calculus", then maybe you should not use the `real-analysis` tag.

Comment: Do you know what the arithmetic mean and geometric mean inequalities are?

Answer (score 3):

The $AM-GM$ inequality tells us that for non-negative $a$ and $b$ we have

$$\frac{a+b}{2}\geq \sqrt{ab}$$

Since $x>0$ then $ax>0$ and by $AM-GM$

$$\frac{ax+\frac{b}{x}}{2}\geq\sqrt{ax\frac{b}{x}}$$

Or $$ax+\frac{b}{x}\geq2\sqrt{ab}$$

with equality when $ax+\frac{b}{x}=2\sqrt{ab}$. Can you end it now?

Comment: I guess I'm confused on what the goal is. Am I trying to solve for x?

Comment: Since $ax+\frac{b}{x}\geq 2\sqrt{ab},$ the minimum value of the expression $ax+\frac{b}{x}$ is $2\sqrt{ab}$ and you obtain the value of $x$ by solving $ax+\frac{b}{x}=2\sqrt{ab}$. Since $x>0$, you can multiply through by $x$ and solve the quadratic. Check using calculus!

Answer (score 0):

Ares has provided an excellent algebraic solution that certainly answers your question. Based on how this site is supposed to work, that answer is better than mine. But I would like to also provide an answer for you that does not jump straight into an algebraic solution; but takes a moment to practice some important mathematical skills for problem solving which come in handy when we are stumped! It is a useful skill in math to learn how to explore a problem if we don't know where to begin on a solution.

**What will the function $f(x) = ax + b/x$ look like? Are we convinced it has a minimum?**

1. When $x$ is small $ax$ is going to be small and not contribute much to the function and $b/x$ will be large and dominate the function. For small $x$ we can expect the function to approximately look like $b/x$, which for any positive value of $b$ will look approximately like the function $1/x$ which is a **decreasing** function.
2. As $x$ grows, $b/x$ will start to get small and contribute less to the function and $ax$ will grow and begin to dominate the function. As $x$ gets very large the function will get closer and closer to the function $ax$, which for all positive values of $a$ is an **increasing** linear function.
3. From our work above we expect that for all positive values $a,b$ our function will switch from decreasing to increasing which guarantees a minimum.

The function out to look something like this:
[image]

If you really want to play around with graphing this function for intuition, you could make a tool like this on desmos which allows you to toggle the values of $a,b$ (though with more practice I don't think this is necessary)

[image]

**Where might the minimum occur?**

We know the minimum should be wherever the function "switches" from $b/x$ to $ax$, but this will depend on the chosen values of $a,b$.

1. If $a$ is large, the function will switch to $ax$ sooner because $ax$ will grow faster. This makes the minimizer smaller.
2. If $b$ is large, the function will switch to $ax$ longer because it will take a larger $x$ to make $b$ small. This will make the minimizer bigger.

**Moving to the algebra**

At this point I am convinced of the existence of the minimum, and I am convinced it will be some function of the numbers $a,b$. I feel more grounded in the problem. I know I need to use the AM-GM inequality which in its simple case states that for any nonnegative $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$\frac{a+b}{2} \geq \sqrt{ab}.$$

Since $x > 0, $a > 0$, $b > 0$ then $ax$ and $b/x$ are both positive real numbers. At this point, the only logical thing to try is top plug the numbers into the inequality to yield

$$\frac{ax + \frac{b}{x}}{2} \geq \sqrt{ax\frac{b}{x}}, \hspace{2mm} \text{ for all} x \in \mathbb{R}$$,

The part about "for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$" is very important!

At this point you can pick up where Ares solution starts. Good luck!